# How to kill port in termux?

Tags: termux

In temux i run on port 8083 node.

In ubuntu i use in package.json this script:

but in termux it is not working.

```
"kill": `"kill $(lsof -t -i:8083)"`
```

I get this eror

```
sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! radio@1.0.0 kill: `kill $(lsof -t -i:8083)`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the radio@1.0.0 kill script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2020-07-15T12_44_45_322Z-debug.log
```

And two variant

"kill": "fuser -k 8083/tcp && echo 'Terminated' || echo 'Nothing thing was running on the PORT'"

```
radio@1.0.0 kill2 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/server-radio
> fuser -k 8083/tcp && echo 'Terminated' || echo 'Nothing was running on the PORT'

Cannot open protocol file "/proc/net/tcp": Permission denied
Nothing was running on the PORT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command

```
 sudo netstat -plten |grep java
```

used `grep java` as `tomcat` uses `java` as their processes.

It will show the list of processes with port number and process id

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      
1000       30070621    16085/java
```

the number before `/java` is a process id. Now use `kill` command to kill the process

```
kill -9 16085
```

`-9` implies the process will be killed forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN)
```

or try with sudo

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8083 -sTCP:LISTEN)
```

Comment: I don't have sudo. without sudo not work. kill: not enough arguments